# jsFiddle works. Implementation on webpage doesn't?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

This js fiddle runs with no errors or problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/3j45B/2/

However, when embedded within http://www.zabb.co.uk/untitled6.html it does not work? Any suggestions please?

---

**EDIT:**

Further to your comments and suggestions below a **solution** has been found, thank you all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.thumbnail2').click(function() {
        src = $(this).attr('src');
        if (src != $('.img').attr('src')) {
            $('.img').fadeOut(250, function() {
                $(this).attr('src', src).fadeIn(250);
            });
        }
    });

});​
```

Important bit to ensure event works is to wrap your jQuery code within:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});​
```

See following link for further information regarding this function:
[Introducing `$(document).ready()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your embedded script in a `$(...)` or `$(document).ready(...)`

jsfiddle did that for you (see the dropdown box on the left that says "onLoad"?).

Comment: Yes. (+1) @Kelly This demonstrates that: http://jsfiddle.net/3j45B/3/ I just took onLoad away.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code. But you probably forgot to include a plugin called Galleria, I get Galleria not defined.

Comment: It's true that there is a ReferenceError being thrown, but that's not what's causing the code not to work. In particular, it (the error) happens after the code in question executes.